# How to start a service at startup

Tags: linux, boot, shell-script, crontab, kodi

I am using Ubuntu Server to make a Kodi box. I'm using kodi-standalone-service to do so. I have made a shell script (sudo -S <<< "password" systemctl start kodi) to start kodi. When I run it mannually it starts kodi as expected. I need it to run at startup though. The only way I could do so (or at least I thought) was to add @reboot /home/main/startupscript.sh to crontab.
And I did so. Now Ubuntu stops after the initial boot log whithout any meaningful error message. And I cant use the terminal. Can you guys help me?
Could it be something to do with xorg even though I have it installed? (clearly as I can run it manually) Maybe the command is ran too soon in the boot process?

Comment: I assume you’ve tried `systemctl enable kodi.service`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to start a service during the boot proccess in a system that uses systemd is by using the `enable` option.

```
systemctl enable kodi.service
```

Regards.

Comment: Oh thank you. I had never used a service before. Should've done a little research xd. I've still got a problem though. I can't exit Kodi. When I do it terminates the X server and stays ok "closing log file.X server" until I reboot... (Power button or shutdown signal as I'm working on a virtual machine). Is it a problem with kodi-standalone-service?

Comment: I have found a way around it. I can just use another tty. It' still bugging me though...

Comment: Glad it worked. I haven't used this service, so I don't really know how it works.